# Como buscar resultados no MySQL onde um determinado campo só tenha caracteres especiais?

Tags: mysql, regex

Estou precisando buscar no MySQL, linhas onde um campo determinado, por exemplo 'Nome', está preenchido somente com caracteres especiais ou espaços em branco.

Tentei diversos REGEX para tal, mas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você precisa que contém algum carácter especial ou somente caracter especial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busque por nomes que não possuam caracteres alfanuméricos.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT `name` from `person` where `name` REGEXP "^[^[:alnum:]]+$"
```

A vantagem no uso dessa expressão: `^[^[:alnum:]]+$` é que identifica caracteres multibyte como sendo válidos dentro da regra de alfanuméricos.

Exemplo

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(100) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `person` VALUES 
(1, 'john doe'),
(2, '( , .'),
(3, '大嶺'),
(4, 'محمد');
```

A regra `^[^[:alnum:]]+$` retornará somente `( , .`.

Outras regras podem retornar nomes válidos. Exemplo, ^[^a-z0-9]+$ retorna:

```
( , .
大嶺
محمد
```

Ainda assim não garante total integridade.

Pode ter casos onde há caracteres como este 　. Note que parece ser um caracter de espaço comum, porém é multibyte, diferente de . Perceba a diferença no tamanho.

É comum encontrar nomes com emoji. Exemplo: `(´・ω・`)`. Os quais também não são detectados por essa regra.

Nesses casos, quando uma regra não detecta. Deve ser feito uma pesquisa específica somente para esses casos especiais ou regras especificas que consigam encontrar os conjuntos especiais.

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE nome REGEXP ^[^a-z0-9]+$
```

retirei o `A-Z`, pois só é preciso se usar o operador `BINARY` para ser case sensitive.

este link: http://programandosemcafeina.blogspot.com.br/2007/04/caracteres-especiais-representados-em.html
tem uma lista de caracteres unicode para personalizar a query a sua maneira.

Comment: Problemas: só captura campos que contenham exatamente um caractere ; não leva em conta unicode, logo vai considerar é, ç, á, etc como caractere especial ; se você corrigir o problema de pegar apenas um caractere ainda assim vai pegar campos que contenham pelo menos 1 caractere especial ou espaço em branco ("Iron Man" por exemplo) sendo que a descrição da questão diz que são campos que contenham apenas estes.

Comment: @BrunoRB quanto a um caractere só, de fato (faltou ele por o + depois do grupo), mas o exemplo do "Iron Man" com espaço não procede. Tem marcação de começo e fim de linha.

Comment: @Bacco true, engano meu. Também na questão não é especificado se unicode é necessário então se o iron adicionar o `+` faltante na regex eu retiro o downvote.

Comment: BrunoRB obrigado por destacar o problema. é o que dar fazer as coisas na pressa e Bacco obrigado pelo crédito.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([[:punct:]]|[[:cntrl:]]|[[:blank:]])+$
```

Vai fazer match de todos os campos que só contêm pontuações ou caracteres de controle ou espaços/quebras-de-linha, o [seguinte fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98f1d/1) contêm um exemplo de uso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz isso em SQL Server e funcional

TABELA EXEMPLO E CONSULTA EXEMPLO

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample(Field varchar(50), Result varchar(50))
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123 ', '1')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123.', '2')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123&', '3')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('&*¨*¨*(', '4')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('&* &^^>*¨*(', '5')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('&* daniel&^^>*¨*(', '6')
SELECT * FROM #Sample WHERE Field NOT LIKE  N'%[0-9A-Za-z]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
GO
DROP TABLE #Sample
```

Veja se isso funciona para MySQL